# Why is returning only last element from array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have this code:

```
$actors = explode(",",$this->input->post('movie_actors', true));
            
foreach ($actors as $value) {
    $actor['name'] = $value;    
}
```

My current output is

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Actor4" }
```

But variable $actors is a list of actors like this: Actor1,Actor2,Actor3,Actor4

Why is getting only last element?

Comment: Each time through the loop you overwrite `$actor['name']`. At the end, it has the last one. What are you expecting instead?

Comment: @Barmar I want to insert in database list like `Actor1,Actor2,Actor3,Actor4` as `id1 -> Actor1, id2 - > Actor2..... ` every actor with row in database, I use codeigniter

Comment: Then put your insert code inside the loop.

Comment: @Barmar 
`foreach ($actors as $value) { $actor[]['name'] = $value; } $this->db->insert('actors', $actor); `It show me string conversion error. Any Ideea?

Comment: It should just be `$actor['name']`. You're only inserting one actor, not an array of actors.

Comment: @Barmar if I put `$actor['name']` it insert only last actor from list

Comment: It shouldn't, because you're inserting it each time.

Comment: Maybe you need to create a new actor array each time: `$actor = ['name' => $value];`

Comment: I don't know much about CodeIgnitor.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach ($actors as $value) { $actor['name'] = $value;  }`

You are getting last element because array $actor having single index 'name'. each time foreach loop run $array['name'] index value is overwrite. so update your loop like this

`foreach ($actors as $value) { $actor[]['name'] = $value; }`

You will get all the actors.

Comment: I want to insert in database like this `$this->db->insert('actors', $actor);` in database I have Columns ID, Actor name. I want to insert all actors!

Comment: `foreach ($actors as $value) { $actor[]['name'] = $value; } $this->db->insert('actors', $actor);`  It show me string conversion error

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this with this code:

```
$actors = explode(",",$this->input->post('movie_actors', true));
            
            foreach ($actors as $value) {
                    
                $data[]['name'] = $value;

            }
            
            $this->db->insert_batch('actors', $actor);
```

The key it was insert_batch and not just insert!